# Android SurfaceView scaling error (ThreadedRenderer)

Tags: java, android, scale, surfaceview, display

> ## Current device I am working with:
>
> ### Samsung Galaxy S6 (SM-G920F)
>
> ### Android 6.0.1
>
> ### 2560 x 1440

I have created a simple game engine using androids surface view (continuous rendering in a separate thread).
I am running into an issue regarding the display metrics of my window. My device seems to have randomly scaled the view port by 0.75 which causes the screen to be displayed incorrectly.

### Error (SRIB_DSS / libEGL), MultiPhoneWindow?

```
01-10 11:21:06.761 23218-23218/? D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
01-10 11:21:06.761 23218-23218/? D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.MultiPhoneWindow$MultiPhoneDecorView{ad58a84 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
01-10 11:21:06.761 23218-23248/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-10 11:21:06.771 23218-23218/? D/MultiPhoneWindow: performUpdateVisibility, same visibility false
01-10 11:21:06.791 23218-23218/? E/SRIB_DSS_ThreadedRenderer: initialize, mIsDcsEnabledApp=true , with format= -1 scaleFactor=0.75
01-10 11:21:06.791 23218-23218/? D/ThreadedRenderer: SRIB_DCS & DSS android_view_ThreadedRenderer_dcs_initialize Rendering in format=-1, factor=0.750000
01-10 11:21:06.791 23218-23218/? D/libEGL: SRIB_DCS:EGL_DCS_setDcsApp format=-1
01-10 11:21:06.791 23218-23218/? E/libEGL: SRIB_DSS: EGL_DSS_setDssApp factor=0.750000
01-10 11:21:06.811 23218-23248/? D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
01-10 11:21:06.821 23218-23248/? D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f8f42b178
01-10 11:21:06.821 23218-23248/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-10 11:21:06.821 23218-23248/? D/: ro.exynos.dss isEnabled: 0
01-10 11:21:06.831 23218-23248/? D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [1920x1080]-format:1
01-10 11:21:06.841 23218-23218/? I/System.out: -----SURFACE CHANGED-----
01-10 11:21:06.841 23218-23218/? I/System.out: Width: 1920
01-10 11:21:06.841 23218-23218/? I/System.out: Height: 1080
01-10 11:21:06.841 23218-23218/? I/System.out: x: 1.0, y: 1.0
01-10 11:21:06.861 23218-23218/? D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
```

I have created a few other application with the same engine and same phone but there is no scaling error. My other device (Moto g XT1032) has no errors. When I uninstall the application the correct scale is used, but when I restart the app it scales by 0.75 again.

### No Error

```
01-10 11:54:54.461 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/SecWifiDisplayUtil: Metadata value : SecSettings2
01-10 11:54:54.461 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{1ba6bd9 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
01-10 11:54:54.461 29397-29728/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
01-10 11:54:54.521 29397-29728/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLES_mali.so
01-10 11:54:54.531 29397-29728/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0x7f9eb7f178
01-10 11:54:54.531 29397-29728/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
01-10 11:54:54.531 29397-29728/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [2560x1440]-format:1
01-10 11:54:54.551 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/System.out: -----SURFACE CHANGED-----
01-10 11:54:54.551 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/System.out: Width: 2560
01-10 11:54:54.551 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/System.out: Height: 1440
01-10 11:54:54.551 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/System.out: x: 2.0, y: 2.0
01-10 11:54:54.601 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=2
01-10 11:54:54.671 29397-29397/particlesystem.com.ds.mo.particlesystem I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@de6d751 time:18008434
```

I get the scaling value in the surface changed method.

```
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    System.out.println("-----SURFACE CHANGED-----");
    System.out.println("Width: " + width);
    System.out.println("Height: " + height);

    //Set Viewports

    //Get the scale value based on the surface created
    scaleX = (float) width / GAME_WIDTH;
    scaleY = (float) height / GAME_HEIGHT;

    //Round scale to 2.d.p
    scaleX = Math.round(scaleX * 100) / 100;
    scaleY = Math.round(scaleY * 100) / 100;

    System.out.println("x: " + scaleX + ", y: " + scaleY);
    resetScaleSwipe();
}
```

The scary thing is that I have released my first game a week ago using said engine, I'm not sure if the problem is with my device. Any help would do, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I have found the solution

*When you release your game to the app store, some Samsung devices will try to  optimize it. By default the output quality is set "Balanced quality" which reduces the resolution to 75% and caps fps @ 60.*

*P.S.Math.round() returns an int so make sure the scaling value is a float by either casting or changing 100 to 100f*

**To fix the issue, you must download Samsungs [game tuner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.samsung.android.gametuner.thin&hl=en) app and change the quality to maximum!**

> Phones affected: Samsung Galaxy series (S6, S6e, S6e+, Note 5)